# Passing variable

Tags: objective-c

Hi I've got an question about passing variables via NSobject into the rootviewcontroller.

I've got 2 .h and .m files ( called viewcontroller.m/h and secondviewcontroller.m/h ).

Underneath a little example for what I'm trying to do.

secondviewcontroller.m

> -(NSString *) mystring{
>
> > return @"this is a string";
>
> }

secondviewcontroller.h

> @interface SecondviewController : NSObject
>
> > -(NSString *) mystring;
>
> @end

How am I be able to pass this variable into viewcontroller.m ?

I've read a lot on google but most of the implementations where wrong or my research is just bad xD

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? In the general sense there are many ways to do what you want. Delegates, or if the second is a member var of the first then it can simply call it. My main reason for commenting here is to ask whether these are actually supposed to be viewcontrollers in uikit? If so you should be deriving from UIViewController not NSObject.

Answer (score 2):

> How am I be able to pass this variable into viewcontroller.m ?

You actually haven't shown us any variables; `-myString` returns a constant string. Also, remember that viewcontroller.m is just an implementation file. It's probably better to think about the *objects* communicating with each other than one piece of source code communicating with another. I communicate with you, but my DNA doesn't communicate with your DNA.

Anyway, it sounds like you're asking about how one object can communicate with another, and the answer is simply that at least one of the objects in the conversation needs to know about the other. So, an instance of your `viewcontroller` class might get a pointer to an instance of `secondviewcontroller` from some other object, or it might create a new instance itself. Some part of the code in `viewcontroller.m` might look like:

```
secondviewcontroller *svc = [[secondviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NSString *someString = [svc myString];
```

That's not a particularly realistic example, but neither is the sample you provided. The lesson is the same, though -- objects communicate by sending messages to each other, and an object needs a reference to another object in order to send that message. Figuring out which objects should know about which others, how they find out about each other, and what messages they send to each other is exactly the business of object oriented programming. In OOP, the truly important thing isn't so much the objects themselves but how they relate to each other. It's all about the structure that you create using objects as building blocks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still figuring this out and being still in learning phase. Your story about this makes me look it more clearer